# STDOUT json format with system command

Tags: python

I have the following example where I want to output a variable in the same json format with os.system (the idea is to output with a system command) but the double quotes are ignored in output.

```
import json
import os
import requests

PAYLOAD_CONF = {
    "cluster": {
      "ldap": "string",
      "processes": 22
    }
}

paystr = (str(PAYLOAD_CONF))
paydic = (json.dumps(PAYLOAD_CONF))

os.system("echo "+paystr+"") 
os.system("echo "+paydic+"")
```

Output:

```
{cluster: {processes: 22, ldap: string}}
{cluster: {processes: 22, ldap: string}}
```

Can you help me in a workaround where I can output this with double quotes? It's very important to output with system command.

Comment: What do you expect `paystr` to look like? Also, you never deal with escaping for the shell that `os.system()` invokes.

Comment: Why this complicated way to print the string?

Comment: I agree, the proper way is to either use `print` or `sys.stdout` for the output, insisting on using `os.system("echo...)` requires an explanation as to what you're trying to achieve by doing that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For cases like this, where you embed variables into a shell command you should use [shlex.quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote). Using this (and with minor cleanup), the code can be written as:

```
import json
import os
import shlex

PAYLOAD_CONF = {
    "cluster": {
        "ldap": "string",
        "processes": 22
    }
}

paydic = json.dumps(PAYLOAD_CONF)

os.system("echo " + shlex.quote(paydic))
```

Output:

```
{"cluster": {"ldap": "string", "processes": 22}}
```

### Using `subprocess`

The [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html) module contains a lot of helper functions for calling external applications. These functions are generally preferrable to use than `os.system` for various security reasons.

If there is no hard dependency of `os.system` you can also use one of depending on your needs:

- [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) -- This will return even if the subprocess fails. If this returns a non-zero value, the process exited abnormally.
- [subprocess.check_call](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) -- This will raise an exception if the process exits abnormally.
- [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) -- This will return `stdout` from the subprocess and raise an exception if it exits abnormally.
- ... The module contains many other helpful functions for interacting with subprocess which you should check out if the above don't suit your needs.

using `check_output`, the code becomes:

```
from subprocess import check_call
import json
import os
import shlex

PAYLOAD_CONF = {
    "cluster": {
        "ldap": "string",
        "processes": 22
    }
}

paydic = json.dumps(PAYLOAD_CONF)

check_call(["echo", paydic])
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not adding quotes; you're adding an empty string to the end.

Also, echo is going to interpret the first set of double quotes as a wrapper around the argument – not as part of the string itself. In the echo command itself, you need to escape double quotes with a backslash, e.g. `echo \"hello\"` will output `"hello"`, whereas `echo "hello"` will output `hello`.

In a Python string, you're going to have to escape the literal backslash in the echo command with another backslash, e.g. `os.system('echo \\"hello\\"')` for output `"hello"`.

Applying this to your case and using [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) to make it easy:

```
import json
import os
import requests

PAYLOAD_CONF = {
    "cluster": {
      "ldap": "string",
      "processes": 22
    }
}

paystr = (str(PAYLOAD_CONF))
paydic = (json.dumps(PAYLOAD_CONF))

os.system('echo \\"{}\\"'.format(paystr)) 
os.system('echo \\"{}\\"'.format(paydic))
```

Output:

```
"{cluster: {ldap: string, processes: 22}}"
"{cluster: {ldap: string, processes: 22}}"
```

Your `paystr` variable is also unnecessary, since all objects are automatically converted to strings by `print` and `format` via their inherited or overridden `__str__` methods.

EDIT:

To output the variable as it appears in Python you just need to iterate through the payload dict and render each key-value pair in a type-sensitive way.

```
import os
import requests

def make_payload_str(payload, nested=1):
    payload_str = "{\n" + "\t" * nested

    for i, k in enumerate(payload.keys()):
        v = payload[k]

        if type(k) is str:
            payload_str += '\\"{}\\"'.format(k)
        else:
            payload_str += str(k)

        payload_str += ": "

        if type(v) is str:
            payload_str += '\\"{}\\"'.format(v)
        elif type(v) is dict:
            payload_str += make_payload_str(v, nested=nested + 1)
        else:
            payload_str += str(v)

        # Only add comma if not last element
        if i < len(payload) - 1:
            payload_str += ",\n" + "\t" * nested
        else:
            payload_str += "\n"

    return payload_str + "\n" + "\t" * (nested - 1) + "}"


PAYLOAD_CONF = {
    "cluster": {
      "ldap": "string",
      "processes": 22
    }
}

paystr = make_payload_str(PAYLOAD_CONF)

os.system('echo "{}"'.format(paystr))
```

Output:

```
{
    "cluster": {
        "ldap": "string",
        "processes": 22

    }

}
```

If the payload contains a dictionary, as it does in the example you provided, the function calls itself to produce the string for that dictionary, indented the right number of tabs using the `nested` parameter.

If the payload is also allowed to have lists and other more complex types, you'll have to include cases that account for those, but it's just more of the same.

Comment: Yes paystr it's not necesarry, the ideea is to have the exact format that was set in PAYLOAD_CONF constant. format() will put double quotes at begining and at the end of the string. I tried with replace but still no luck.